# Explanation about substitution in integrating

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have $$4\int_0^{+\infty}\int_0^{+\infty}(e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dy)dx$$ then I let $y=xs$ thus $dy=xds$ and the integral becomes $$4\int_0^{+\infty}\int_0^{+\infty}(e^{-x^2(1+s^2)}xds)dx$$
I understand that this substitution is a way to get rid of $y$ by introducing some parameter $s$ but I do not understand why is $dy=xds$ when $x$ is a variable as well and here it seems to me we are considering it simply as a coeffiecient?

The mentioned substitution is used in Laplace's approach to show that $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}$

Comment: If you only consider the inner integral then $x$ is a constant. Therefore the derivative $\frac{d}{ds} xs = x$.

Comment: The inner integral is then computed with $s$ and $ds$, $x$ is still a constant.

Comment: Thank you, I'm a bit of a dummy for multivariable calculus.

Comment: Remember to always think of the "context" and what is a constant and what is not. When first computing the inner integral, you can completely forget about $x$. Just write $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2(1+x^2)} x ds$ on another sheet of paper and solve it only taking $s$ into account :)